# porting .apk to BlackBerry 10 - external .jar error

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android, android-async-http

I have an android project which I would like to port to BlackBerry 10. Acording to BB online repackaging tool the project is BAR compatible. So I added the BlackBerry nature using their Eclipse plugin and loaded it into BB 10 Simulator. But the app craches since BB obviously does not recognize the `android-async-http` library used in the project:

```
 02-13 08:22:14.228: E/AndroidRuntime(28778620): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 02-13 08:22:14.228: E/AndroidRuntime(28778620):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
 02-13 08:22:14.228: E/AndroidRuntime(28778620):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
 02-13 08:22:14.228: E/AndroidRuntime(28778620):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
 02-13 08:22:14.228: E/AndroidRuntime(28778620): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient
```

I don't know the BlackBerry 10 system architecture so I'm a bit lost. Is there any way to get it working on BB10?

Answer (score 2):

This library `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient` seems to be a third party library for Android.  According to the BB10 Android Runtime docs, the use of third party libraries is [not currently supported](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_software_features.html).

> Add on libraries (all libraries defined by the tag in the app's
>   manifest other than "android.test.runner" are unsupported)

I'm not sure why the online packager didn't report this as a problem, but you might want to see what the Eclipse plugin repackager reports instead.  In the end, you will probably need to replace your use of this library with a core Android API call like [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) instead.